# Как в notification отключить Service?

Tags: android, service

В приложении Android создана служба, которая периодически проверяет данные в интернете. Предположим, она запущена и работает. Как только проверяемые данные изменятся - на смартфоне появится соответствующее уведомление. Уведомление содержит заголовок, текст и две кнопки. По нажатию первой кнопки открывается приложение. Вот и вопрос: как по нажатию второй кнопки реализовать остановку службы (stopService)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте

```
stopService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
```

Comment: в setAction() передавайте какую-нибудь строку, типа "STOP_SERVICE" в onReceive() получайте таким образом: String action = intent.getAction(). Потом проверяйся, что за действие и вызывайте соответствующую логику

Comment: @Владимир прикрепите к вопросу код, чтобы понятней было

Comment: Благодарю, сделал так, как вы описали в первом комментарии. Помогло. Правда, пришлось изучить тему Receiver'ов и PendingIntent.

Comment: @Владимир Ну вот видите, будет плюсом=)